# Reference on a variant of the Lagrange's four-square theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-forms

Recently I read the wonderful autobiography "I want to be a Mathematician" by Paul Halmos and came across the following passage:

> "My first research was inspired by Carmichael. He told us about a peculiar question (inspired perhaps by the four square theorem): for
>   which positive integers $a, b, c, d$ is it true that every positive integer is
>   representable by the form $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + dt^ 2$? (" Representable " -
>   means via integral values of the variables $x, y, z, t$.) The answer is that
>   there are exactly 54 such forms, and Ramanujan determined them all.
>   My question was: which forms of the same kind represent every positive
>   integer with exactly one exception? I found 88 candidates, proved that
>   there could be no others, and proved that 86 of them actually worked.
>   (Example: $x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 + 29t^2$ fails to represent 14 only.)"

I googled but couldn't find anything about this cute problem. I would really like any reference for the work Ramanujan did on this problem and the aftermost work done by Halmos.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183511882

Comment: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/290-Theorem-preprint.pdf